# How will I know the command was executed?

Tags: java, android, runtime.exec

I comunicate with the console application with **getRuntime().exec()** on **Android**.
This code:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(true ? "su" : "sh");
// InputStream for program
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
//I output info on screen in Gobbler
StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new 
                    StreamGobbler(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");      
StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new 
                    StreamGobbler(process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
```

How will I know **command1** was executed?

```
os.writeBytes(command1 + "\n");
// Here
os.writeBytes(command2 + "\n");
```

**process.waitFor()** wait until the process represented by this Process object has terminated.
Thanks!

---

I will know command2, after getting output of command1.

---

This is not duplicate question. [@Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard), in my case **process.watFor()** will not execute. And it will be wait while I don't send **os.write("exit"+"\n")**. I think that my question don't have normal answer. The only way - parse output of process.

Comment: You already answered to your question.

Comment: Ok, But I am unable to understand what exactly your question is?

Comment: waitFor() waiting for the end of the process, but not one of the command

Comment: I may be wrong but I guess the are sequential they will be executed one by one.

Comment: But I know what to enter further, only getting output of the previous command. (I want to get interactive communication with the process)

Comment: You have to parse the output and error streams for the process, in order to tell if a command has been completed. This is a poor use case though, `Runtime.exec` is really not built for interactive programming.

Comment: What can I use in this situation?